# Does the resource URL in webApplicationInfo need to contain the Microsoft Teams App ID?

Tags: azure, terraform, botframework, microsoft-teams, pulumi

My teams app uses a bot and is configured for SSO, the webApplicationInfo property in my manifest looks something like this [following this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-manifest):

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{Azure AD AppId}",
    "resource": "api://{Subdomain}.example.com/botid-{Azure AD AppId}"
    }
```

The resource URL is ultimately used as the Application ID URI and Redirect URI in my bot's app registration and then is also used as the Token Exchange URL in my bot's connection.

The current set up works well, but I want to automate the creation of the bot in Azure using Terraform or Pulumi. However, because the resource URL in webApplicationInfo is structured to include the App ID, the creation process for the app registration has a self-referential problem: **the Application ID URI and Redirect URI can't be configured during creation because the App ID isn't available until after the app registration is created.**

**What purpose does including the App ID in the resource URL serve?** Is it essential for me to include? Will I run into issues down the road? Excluding it from the URL would solve these self-referential problems.

Comment: You cannot set the URIs (or indeed make any modifications to the registration) until after it has been created. You will need to design your automation sequence to perform these tasks after creating the registration. To my knowledge, the `AppId` is required to expose an API that links to your application. Perhaps someone from Teams can chime in on that particular point.

Comment: @AP01 do you have any documentation you could link about the AppId? I've struggled to find places where it explains the format apart from some sample code.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find docs on the App ID specifically, but essentially it's an alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies an Azure application of any type. You must have it because without it, Azure will have no idea which application you're communicating with. One subdomain could have multiple Azure apps on it. It's a bit like needing a username to log into a website.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have an error in your code sample: it's not `botid-{Azure AD AppId}`, but rather just `{Azure AD AppId}`. That means it's the *same* AppId as the line above. A complete example would look something like this (with a sample app id):

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "3bbd1472-40d9-4852-bee6-33e16739a7b7",
    "resource": "api://myApi.example.com/3bbd1472-40d9-4852-bee6-33e16739a7b7"
    }
```

That aside, you definitely need to have this id, but the sequence for Terraform /Pullumi should be ok. It should be:

1. Create Azure App, get it's Id
2. Create Bot (you can specify the Azure App Id you created above, as being the App Id to use)
3. Create the Teams manifest using the Azure App Id

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the current set up works for SSO. The syntax isn't wrong, the same syntax is used in sample code from Microsoft, [like here for example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/c173c0e7a316df7425db1d795713e46c00594632/samples/app-sso/nodejs/teamsAppManifest/manifest.json). 

Your answer doesn't address the self-referential aspect of my question, but I guess since the bot id appears to be necessary in this url, I must try to update the resources after creation using Pulumi or Terraform. 

Regardless, thank you for the reply.