# adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_resource|AADSTS500011

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to build a simple Teams tab app that lists the members of a team. I've used the Teams Toolkit for VS Code to generate the boilerplate. Running the app using F5 works fine. So far, so good.

Next I'm trying to read the team members from Graph. I've read about RSC (resource-specific consent) which seems to be exactly what I need. Because I want to prevent the app from opening any permission popups or login popups (other than the one appearing during the installation).

So I've followed the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent and I've also made the check. Works fine.

However, as soon as I'm running the code locally (using F5), I'm getting this error:

```
AUTHMSAL: Event: adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_resource|AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://localhost:53000/MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID was not found in the tenant named MYTESTTENANT. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

I've double checked: the tenant *does* exist (and there's only this one). The app id is also correct, it resembles the one I've added using the "App registration". I've also added a "Client secret", however I'm not exactly sure where to add it to my code. This is probably the root cause of my problem.

The relevant parts of my code are:

```
// manifest.template.json

{
 ...
 "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID",
    "resource": "api://localhost:53000/MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID"
  },
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "TeamSettings.Read.Group",
          "type": "Application"
        },
        {
          "name": "TeamMember.Read.Group",
          "type": "Application"
        },
        // ... (I've added *all* other permissions, too, just for testing...)
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Tab.tsx

// ...

// I've read on NPM that useTeamsFx() is deprecated and switched to useTeamsUserCredential()
const all = useTeamsUserCredential({
  clientId: "MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID",
  initiateLoginEndpoint: "fooBarInitiateLoginEndpoint",
  // ...don't I have to add my clientSecret somewhere?
});
```

```
// Welcome.tsx

// ...
const { loading, error, data, reload } = useGraphWithCredential(
  async (graph, credential, scope) => {
    await graph.api(`/teams/MY-GROUP-ID/members`).get() // leads to the error
  },
  {
    scope: [
      "TeamMember.Read.Group"
    ],
    credential
  }
)
```

I've also tried to follow the AddSSO guide, but it led to permission popups which I want to prevent. Plus it added a lot of AAD specific stuff (like aad.template.json), which I don't need, because RSC suffices in my case (...right?).

Also, my app doesn't need SSO (...right?) because it only lists the members of the team and it runs inside Teams only...

**EDIT**

I've also tried `new TeamsFx(IdentityType.App)` instead of `useTeamsUserCredential()` (because RSC permissions have `"type": "Application"` in the `manifest.template.json`), however this ended up in an error:

```
Uncaught ErrorWithCode.IdentityTypeNotSupported: Application identity is not supported in TeamsFx
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else may be able to provide you a full Teams example, but the main error in your case is this one:

```
AUTHMSAL: Event: adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_resource|AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://localhost:53000/MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID was not found in the tenant named MYTESTTENANT. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

The reason for this is here:

```
 "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID",
    "resource": "api://localhost:53000/MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID"
  },
```

`"api://localhost:53000/MY-CLIENT-ID-UUID"` is not a valid resource identifier. Please note that this is not the API url, but rather its identifier. Please look for the **App Id URI** in your application registration in Azure Portal.

The correct value is most likely `api://<your-client-id>`, but you need to set it first.

See also [Does the resource URL in webApplicationInfo need to contain the Microsoft Teams App ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73791564/does-the-resource-url-in-webapplicationinfo-need-to-contain-the-microsoft-teams)

`https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/~/Overview/appId/<your-client-id>/`

[image: AAD App]

[image: Set Uri]

[image: Value]

Comment: Indeed! I had to set it to `api://localhost:53000/MY-CLI[...]` to avoid an iframe src error. Now a popup appears "Almost complete!", but clicking on "Continue" fails:
`AUTHMSAL: Event: adal:tokenRenewFailure, code: invalid_client|AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: 5e[...]46(Microsoft Teams Web Client). Resource value from request: api://localhost:53000/MY-CLI[...]. Resource app ID: MY-CLI[...]. List of valid resources from app registration: .`

Comment: Any chance of helping me with the error in my above comment?

Comment: The error is very similar to the original one mentioned in my answer. Note that even if you call that localhost, this is not an actual callable url. It is just an identifier. Look at the api permissions in the Azure Portal. You need at least the same permissions as you defined in the scopes in the questions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-microsoft-graph so this might be "TeamMember.Read.Group". Depending on your app you might need to define an additional custom api permission on the app.

Comment: See, this is exactly the thing that confuses me about RSC. I thought the whole point about RSC is that it doesn't require fumbling around in Azure permissions, but instead can be configured solely in the manifest.json. At least this is how I understood the docs: `The Azure AD portal cannot be used to request RSC permissions. RSC permissions are currently exclusive to Teams applications installed in the Teams client and are declared in the Teams app manifest (JSON) file.`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent

Comment: @kraftwer1 interesting. It seems you can only run the code locally through teams, so not as a standalone app. Only the backend runs locally, the frontend must be uploaded to teams. At least that is how I read it. There is a code sample in the docs you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but the sample is only in Node.js (???) and also the docs don't explain what to do with the client secret...

Comment: @kraftwer1 there is also a dotnet sample that includes information about the client secret https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-rsc/csharp